# How to filter a GridViewDataComboBoxColumn that has the enable call back property turned on?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using callbacks to populate a GridViewDataComboBoxColumn and other columns based on the value of another GridViewDataComboBoxColumn.

using `<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s, e) {  populateDefaults(s); }"></ClientSideEvents>`This functionality is working, but when i try to filter the ASPxGridView i got this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SetValue' of null`

How can I skip EndCallback function when the user uses the filter?

[image: my grid]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, and I want to share it. I tried to call my function when the edit form is showen using `if (ASPxGridView1.IsEditing()) {.....}` and it worked !